# Eliminating the repeated values of a key in a DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas

I've been working with the following data frame:

```
import pandas as pd
from collections import OrderedDict
 
df = pd.DataFrame({'ID' : ['ID1', 'ID1'], "pdb" : ["a", "b"], "beg": [1, 2], "end" : [10, 11]})

for index, row in df.iterrows(): 
    df['range'] = [list(x) for x in zip(df['beg'], df['end'])]     
    df['new'] = df.apply(lambda x : " ".join(list(map(str,range(x['beg'],x['end']+1)))),axis=1)
    df2 = df.groupby(["ID"], sort=False)['new'].apply((lambda x : ','.join(x.astype(str)))).reset_index(name='new')  
    df2['Desired'] = (df2['new'].str.split().apply(lambda x: OrderedDict.fromkeys(x).keys()).str.join(' '))
```

And I'm struggling with the last line.
Basically, now every "ID" has a "new" key that holds all the values betwen every "beg" and "end",
ie:

```
    ID                                          new
0  ID1  1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10, 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11
```

And what I'm trying to do is getting only the numbers not repeated on the "new" key, counting every number, no matter if they are separeted by a "," (that's what the list line is for, which is not working)
What I'm getting looks like this:

```
     ID                     Desired
0  ID1  1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10, 10 11
```

What I'm trying to get looks like this:

```
    ID  Desired
0  ID1  1 11
```

I've seen this question in a couple of posts here, but non of the answers worked correctly. Thanks!
Edit: If you have more than 3 rows, it should check all of them, ie:
It should also check in every row, ie:

```
  ID  new
0 ID1 1 [..] 10, 2 [...] 11, 2 [...] 10, 40 [...] 60, 100 [...] 120, 100 [...] 110
```

should return:

```
  ID   Desired
0 ID1  1 11 40 60 100 120
```

Comment: What happens if you have 3 rows?

Comment: It should also check in every row, ie: 1 [..] 10, 2 [...] 11, 40 [...] 60 should return: 1 11 40 60

Comment: For a quick and simple fix, you could just modify your code to include try statements (and then catch and handle the errors from the bad keys accordingly).

Comment: please provide a more complete example (e.g. several rows for `ID1`) along with the desired result.

Comment: Also: are you looking for interval compaction (i.e. the result should contain a new set of contiguous ranges expressed by `beg` and `end`), or just a set of numbers not repeated among your rows? (In which case: is it: not repeated at all, or not repeated in all rows)?

Comment: I just added a more complex example. Regarding the second question, the latest, I'm looking for the not repeated numbers on every row (for every ID, how the total length of the "beg" and "end", accounting for the overlapping of every set)

Comment: what happens to `41..59` in your new example? These numbers are not repeated, but they don't show up in your desired output.

Comment: Great question, I didn't realized about it. My bad. In that case, even that they are not repeated, it should also only inform the first and last numbers (40 and 60), even though they are not repeated. At the end, I should be able to get the total amount of 'mapping' for every PDB, ie 50 in the last example.

Comment: so, what is the desired output if one ID has three rows with intervals: `[0, 10]`, `[2, 8]`, `[4, 6]`? Some numbers are repeated, some are not...

Comment: I think you need to clarify the _meaning_ of your `desired` column: are those endpoints of new intervals, or a set of values not covered by every interval?

Comment: In your example, the result should be 0 10, because within the first interval you cover the other two. They are endpoints of new intervals.

Comment: My point is that, eventually, you'll come to realize that you are looking for interval compaction: a new set of intervals based on the cover of your original intervals. For example, if I understand your desired logic, `[0, 10]`, `[5, 15]`, `[3, 12]` would flag the set of numbers `{1, 2, 3, 4, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15}`; reducing that to `[1, 4]`, `[11, 15]` is interval compaction.

Comment: Yes, but when you the see real coverage of those sequences, you can tell that it goes from 0 to 15! Even though the numbers 0 from 4 are not repeated. That the issue. I really did a bad job at explaining it, sorry

Comment: but the numbers from `[5, 10]` are repeated everywhere; doesn't that mean they should be excluded from the desired result? If not, why wouldn't `[min(beg), max(end)]` be a valid answer?

Comment: It would be a valid answer, but if you had someting like 1 [...] 10, 2 [...] 10, 40 [...] 60, if Im correct, you would get 1 60, where the real coverage goes from 1 10 and 40 60, there´s no coverage in between. In the example that you just gave, the entire coverage goes from 0 to 15, it includes the numbers that are repeated (5 to 12) and the ones that are not (0 to 5)